# Check credential before requesting the Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services

For a WebService, How can I check the credential before requesting the WebService?

In this exemple we are using a bad password to simulate a `HTTP 401 : Unauthorized.`.
Is there a way before the `var param = DoComplexeWork();` to validate the credential?

```
string UserName = "FOOBAR_USR";
string SecurelyStroredPassword = "FOOBAR_BAD_PWD";
string Domain = "FOOBAR_DOM";
string Url = "https://example.com/Foo/Bar.svc";

CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
credentialCache.Add(
    new Uri(Url),
    "Basic",
    new NetworkCredential(UserName, SecurelyStroredPassword, Domain)
);

var iFoo = new MyFooBarWebService();
iFoo.Credentials = credentialCache;

//Check if Credential is OK 
var param = DoComplexeWork();
var result = iFoo.CreateBar(param);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validating the credentials are made on each request. So you need another URL to request that only validates the credentials.

Depending on your webservice you might be able to make a HEAD request. But that may or may not trigger the actual processing as well.

So there is no obvious easy way to do this, because of the underlying HTTP protocol.